# Page refreshes (unwanted) when method is called

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, v-for

I am trying to dynamically genenrate more input fields using vuejs when the user clicks a button. My code works very briefly (generating more fields), but for some reason after that, the page refreshes automatically, setting the user back to where they started.
This is my code

```
<div class='wordsdiv'>
     <div id='onedictspec' v-for='arrayspot in wordupload.wordinput.length'>
         <input type='text' class='inputwordtext' v-model='wordupload.wordinput[arrayspot - 1][0]'>
         <input type='text' class='inputwordtext' v-model='wordupload.wordinput[arrayspot - 1][1]'>
     </div>
</div>
<div id='morewords'>
    <button class='morewordsbtn active hover' v-on:click='morewords'>More words</button>
</div>
```

And this is  my javascript inside Vue, data

```
  wordupload: {
      wordinput: [['','']]
 }
```

And the method

```
 morewords: function () {
  oldcount = this.wordupload.wordinput.length
  newcount = oldcount + 10
  while (oldcount <  newcount){
    this.wordupload.wordinput.push(["", ""])
    oldcount += 1
  }
}
```

Basically two input fields are generated for every item in the wordupload.wordinput list, so I try to make more fields by adding more items to wordinput. But for some reason, after calling morewords, the page refreshes, returning to the original situation.

Comment: Are these inputs and button inside a form tag? I'm not familiar with Vue, but it sounds like you might need to stop the event propagation. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers

Comment: @helb You don't want to stop the event propagation, you want to prevent the default event behaviour.

Comment: Ah, right. Thanks for correction :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Vue's documentation

> Order matters when using modifiers because the relevant code is
>   generated in the same order. Therefore using @click.prevent.self will
>   prevent all clicks while @click.self.prevent will only prevent clicks
>   on the element itself.

You need to add `.prevent` to your `v-on:click` so it becomes `v-on:click.self.prevent`